# Why aren't all my tabs listed when trying to close all?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bugs

I'm running Android 5.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

One thing I've noticed when trying to clean up program tabs is that there seems to be a limit on the number of tabs displayed any time I press the Tab (lower left) button.

So if I close all the tabs listed then press the button again, a new slew of program tabs appears. I would expect to be able to swipe away all apps in one go.

Is this a bug? A feature? Any way to change the options leading to this behavior?

Comment: I've got this problem too, you are not the only one:)